# Magento REST API Cannot add products (Nonce and Invalid attribute SKU)

Tags: magento-1.9, rest-api, create-product

I'm new to Magento REST APIs. I've been trying to POST a product to my Magento store through Postman. OAuth 1.0 is authorized and I've checked it by updating a product and getting product details which works fine. The problem arises when I try to insert a new product. First time when I click the send button it shows me the Error

> oauth_problem=nonce_used

[image: This the screen shot for the first error]

And when I try to send it again it shows me a different error

> **Invalid attribute \"sku\": The value of attribute \"SKU\" must be unique**

[image: This is the screen shot for 2nd error]

Comment: Check that sku in admin product, it would be already exist

Comment: But why should it already be there when I'm getting an error on saving for the first time. But yes it is there. But it shouldn't be.